# Making Browsersync work with html5 history api

Tags: javascript, url-routing, browser-sync, html5-history

I'm having trouble making browsersync work with HTML5 history API. I made a simple project you can check here [Github repo](https://github.com/poillic/browsersync-history).

The main issue is that the history.pushstate doesn't apply on others synchronized devices so I can't properly simulate navigation through the app.

--- Edit asked by Matus Dubrava ---

Here's my front js script

```
var a = document.querySelector( 'a' );

a.addEventListener('click', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ta");
    history.pushState(null, null, '/foo');
});
```

And there's gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const historyFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', () => {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './static',
      middleware: [
        historyFallback()
      ]
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

I may be not clear enough; don't hesitate to ask if you want more details.

Comment: Please, don't make us search github repositories, post the code here and show us where exactly things go wrong.

Comment: Edit done, thanks for the feedback !